# Making a welcome page of an android applicaiton

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make a welcome page (.xml file) that will only show on the first time after the user downloaded the application

How can I make that?

Answer (score 6):

To achieve this you can use `SharedPreferences`.

When this activity opened then save the value in preferences to true. and check next time If its value if false then open otherwise not.

Before you open activity then check it.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("data",MODE_PRIVATE);
int number = sharedPref.getInt("isOpened", 0);
if(number == 0) {
    //Open this activity and set this so that next it value is 1 then this conditin will be false.
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
    prefEditor.putInt("isOpened",1);
    prefEditor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to detect the first launch of the application.

To do so you can do one thing.

1. Use SharedPreference to store a value first_launch which will  be by default true.
2. After launching the application check the value if it is first run
   a. if first_lunch true show the welcome page and make it false
   b. if first_lunch false then just start your main activity

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to store something in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
        if(sp.getBoolean("old", false))){
            // start the real 1st Activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, com.example.Activity));
            finish();
        }else{
            sp.edit().putBoolean("old", true).commit();
        }
    }

    // add the use once screen stuff here
}
```